# Color part doesn't works , Error in Code React defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, button, colors, title

*Hi, I am trying to style it using defaultProps. Title part is Ok i added correctly but  color part doesn't works.  where should I change?

```html
import React from 'react'
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function Button({title,color}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button style={{color: {color}}}>{title}</button>
    </div>
  )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  title:'add',
  color:"green",
  backgroundColor:"orage"
}
// Button.propTypes = {
//   color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
//   backgroundColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
//   title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
// }

export default Button
```

Comment: You have a typo in the color `style={{color: color}}`, you are passing it as an object by itself

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing it, will not work as it must be an object.

Check this. Im holding the styles into a separate field for better understanding.

```js
function Button({ title, color }) {
  const styles = { color }; // shorthand syntax as property and value are same name
  return (
    <div>
      <button style={styles}>{title}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  title: "add",
  color: "green",
  backgroundColor: "orage"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}
```